# How to save (pickle) a model instance in pyomo

Tags: python, pyomo

I want to create a model instance and then save it so I can load and solve at a later time (the initialization takes quite long compared to the solving).
When I tried this it gave me the following error.

```
with open('model.pickle', 'w') as f:
    pickle.dump(instance, f)
```

AttributeError:
Can't pickle local object 'Euphemia.**init**..obj_expression

The objective function is this:

```
    def obj_expression(model):
        curve = sum(model.x[area, hour, Type, index] * model.Q[area, hour, Type, index] * 
                    ( model.P1[area, hour, Type, index] + model.P0[area, hour, Type, index] ) / 2  
                        for (area, hour, Type, index) in model.Curve )
        bids = sum(model.y[area, index] * model.PB[area, index] * 
                       sum( model.QB[area, index, hour] for (hour) in model.Hours ) 
                               for (area, index) in model.Bids  )
        return curve + bids
    self.model.OBJ = pe.Objective(rule = obj_expression, sense = pe.maximize)
```

does anybody know how to save a concrete model?

Comment: Do you have lambda functions or something? Those might be difficult to pickle.

Comment: No they are all regular functions.

Comment: Without seeing the details of your model it's impossible to know what is causing pickle to fail. Pyomo models should be pickleable and there are unit tests verifying this: https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/master/pyomo/core/tests/unit/test_pickle.py

Comment: I added the objective function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is the cloudpickle module, regular pickle has problems pickling functions. An example:

```
import cloudpickle

with open('test.pkl', mode='wb') as file:
   cloudpickle.dump(instance, file)


with open('test.pkl', mode='rb') as file:
   instance = cloudpickle.load(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like pickle (and also cloudpickle) will not work when DerivativeVar is used.

```
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.dae import *
import pickle
import dill
model = ConcreteModel()
model.x = ContinuousSet(initialize=(0., 1.))
model.y = Var(model.x, initialize=1.)
with open('model1.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(model, f)

model.dydx = DerivativeVar(model.y, wrt=model.x)
with open('model2.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    try:
        pickle.dump(model, f)
    except TypeError:
        dill.dump(model, f)
```

dill appears to work instead for pickling a weakref: [Pickling weakref in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23644920/pickling-weakref-in-python)