# Save Pyomo model Variable

Tags: python, pyomo

I'm doing an optimization problem and after give the command:

```
results = solver.solve(model,tee=True)
```

I will have all my variables solved inside the model object.

There is a way to save and load this model object?

Comment: if you want solve the whole model, including the results, the you can cloudpicke it as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51181213/8784382). Otherwise, you can just exctract the variable values and store them through a common python library to a file.

Answer (score 1):

The variables will be inside your "model" object, if you have a variable called "A":

```
model.A.value
```

will give you its value (or model.A[index].value if it is indexed)

- If you just want to use the results later in your code
  just call the value when needed (as shown above)
- If you want to save them for later
  The best is to have a function that exports the results towards dictionaries, panda dataframes, and then you can save to txt, csv or excel files using pickle or pandas for excel.
- You can also save your entire model to a file using "cloudpickle" (it will however not work if you try to open it with a too different environment)