# How to copy a pyomo instance from another pyomo instance in a way that the bindings between the two are broken?

Tags: copy, instance, pyomo

I'm using Pyomo 5.6.4 to create Instance_1. At some point, I want to have a duplicate instance which I call Instance_2 from Instance_1. From there, some of the Instance_2 attributes like its objective functions formulation change but I don't want these changes to impact Instance_1. Python copy module (Instance_2 = copy.copy(Instance_1)) didn't work, nor did saving and reading the original Instance_1 as per this post ([How to save (pickle) a model instance in pyomo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50834258/how-to-save-pickle-a-model-instance-in-pyomo))

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

The recommended way to clone a model instance is with `newmodel = model.clone()`.

Comment: Where is the documentation on the `clone` method?  I can't seem to find it even after searching `site: https://pyomo.readthedocs.io "clone"`